# Laravel remove public from url

Tags: php, .htaccess, laravel, laravel-5

This is my folder structure for Laravel 5.2

```
-laravel
--app
--bootstrap
--config
...
```

Under the `laravel` folder that is root of Laravel, I added an `.htaccess` file with following code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
```

Now when I open project in browser I get the error:

> Sorry, the page you are looking for could not be found. "NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 161:"

I am using XAMPP. Why I am getting this error? How can I remove public from the URL using this method?

Answer (score 1):

You need to point your web server to a `public` directory instead of project root directory. Use original `.htaccess` and these Apache settings:

```
DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/public"
<Directory "C:/xampp/htdocs/public">
```

Restart Apache to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to create a virtual host in xampp and set its DocumentRoot to laravel public folder.
Here is a nice tutorial on how to create vhosts in xampp

`https://delanomaloney.com/2013/07/10/how-to-set-up-virtual-hosts-using-xampp/`

Answer (score 0):

create a folder and name as you want, move all the files inside that folder except public, move the content of public folder to root. After you must edit index.php and change [newFolder] by your news folders name

```
require __DIR__.'/[newFolder]/bootstrap/autoload.php';
$app = require_once __DIR__.'/[newFolder]/bootstrap/app.php';
```

Comment: I followed this, but no success. Is there anything else which may be stopping this method. I have tested this in a another machine but its not working in my machine. I have tried it several times but no success. I am not able to understand whats happening.

Comment: with that method you can remove the public URI, so just get your .htaccess file as default and try what I said :) @Mukesh

Answer (score 0):

•Go to mainproject/public>>

```
a.  .htacess
b.  favicon.ico
c.  index.php
d.  robots.txt
e.  web.config
```

1.cut these 5 files from public folder,and then paste on the main project folder that’s means out side of public folder… mainproject/files

2.Next after paste ,open index.php ,modify

```
•require __DIR__.'/…/bootstrap/autoload.php';  to
•require __DIR__.'/bootstrap/autoload.php';

    modify

    $app = require_once DIR.'/../bootstrap/app.php'; to

    $app = require_once DIR.'/bootstrap/app.php';
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your `httpd.conf` file from

```
DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs"
<Directory "C:/xampp/htdocs">
```

to

```
DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/{projectname}/public"
<Directory "C:/xampp/htdocs/{projectname}/public">
```

restart apache. then you can now access your project in url localhost/

Comment: use this in xammp